# C# Database not saving

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I've linked a Microsoft Access database to my Visual Studio project and using the data sources I have included a data grid view to modify the data. When I dragged and dropped the data grid view onto my project it automatically added the tool strip but when I try to save the modified data by pressing the save icon it won't save it permanently, meaning I can't close the program and re-open it with the same changes.

I looked at the code for the save button and even changed it to the official Microsoft support page code so it displays a message if it saves successfully and if not, however even though it's telling me it's saved correctly when I re-open the project no changes has been saved?

Here's the code for the save button I have so far:

```
private void modulesBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.modulesBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.modulesTableAdapter.Update(this.modulesDatabaseDataSet.Modules);
            MessageBox.Show("Saved succesfully","Save Success",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to save. Make sure all modified data is the correct data type.","Save Failed",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure your database file is not being over-written in your compile/execute cycle. If that's the case, you may need to mark the file as "Do Not Copy" in the properties tab in Visual Studio.

Comment: This fixed it! I changed the database file properties within Visual Studio because it was saved as 'always copy' like you suggested and then changed the file location to the debug/bin folder because it wouldn't run, however after doing this it worked and now saves everything fine, thanks!

Comment: Cool! Always glad to help!